# How do I plot multiple lines through multiprocessing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

```
from pylab import *;
from multiprocessing import Pool;

x = np.load('x.npy'); # Shape: 50001
y = np.load('y.npy'); # Shape: 50001x10240
z = np.arange(10240);

figure(num=0, figsize=(16,10));
subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=0.08, right=0.92, top=0.92, wspace=0., hspace=0.);
ax1 = subplot(111);
ax1.set_xlabel('X', size=20); ax1.set_ylabel('Y', size=20);
ax1.set_ylim(50,200);
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels(): tl.set_fontsize(20);
for tl in ax1.get_xticklabels(): tl.set_fontsize(20);
title('Title', size=20);

def f(i):
    ax1.plot(x, y[i], 'k-', alpha=0.005);

def handler():
    p = Pool(8);
    p.map(f,z);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler();
    savefig('image.png');
```

I have a large npy file with 10240 datasets of length 50001 each to be plotted on the same plot. Unfortunately, all I get is a blank plot at the end because the `ax1.plot()` inside the function `f` doesn't actually make a difference outside the function to the real plot.

How do I fix this? How do I let `f` manipulate `ax1` in a proper permanent fashion?

It works if I don't parallelize it, but I can't find a way to parallelize :(

Comment: I don't think that you can parallelize the plotting in matplotlib. That being said I don't think it makes sense to plot that many points, since the can't be shown on screen or printed on paper. the usual workaround here is that you subsample or visualize accumulated statistics (like density maps). These could be computed in different processes and hand their result back to the main process, which then does the plotting.

Comment: Regardless of how many datapoints I am using, I still want to parallelize plotting.

Comment: I doubt that it's gonna work and I don't really see the point either. What can be very useful, though, is to be able to produce multiple figures in parallel. Matplotlib is readily usable for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
global ax1
```

at the start of f().

Comment: How do I pass a single variable to the function while using `Pool.map`

Comment: Sorry, I should have had a closer look at what you were doing. It's not straightforward to pass ax1 into f as an argument. I've edited my answer.Does global ax1 work?

Comment: Why should global work in a multiprocessing environment? The different process don't share the same context.